# Animating a bar in horizontal direction in ios

Tags: ios, uiview, uibezierpath, quartz-core, cabasicanimation

I am using a UIView and UILabel within an UIView to show a horizontal bar adjusting its frame with animations . The final bar looks like [image: Bar]

Is there a better way to achieve. Thanks

Comment: Pls put your code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [UIProgressView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will work for you? It is the standard iOS SDK component for a progress bar.